# Проблемы с AutoScroll Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго время суток. В Panel по клику Button включаются и показываются Label-ы, Button-ы и TextBox-ы. В Panel-е AutoScroll=true (эта часть работает). Все элементы отображаются по порядку, но после выхода за пределы указанных размеров Panel следующие элементы появляются ниже чем должно быть. После перезапуска приложение пустоты исчезают и все встают на свои места. Уже второй день бьюсь. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: Появляется пустое места]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: WinForms? Добавьте метку.

Comment: Да, WinForms. Стоит ли смотреть в сторону WPF

Comment: Покажите код, о котором идет речь, давайте без телепатии и гаданий по скриншотам.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)